# Setting registry 0 or 1, error:vbscript process reported unknown error code 1

Tags: vbscript, electron, electron-builder, regedit, electron-packager

[image]I am trying to assign registry value to 1 or 0. Electron packager and electron behaves differently. I set the value of registry to 0 and 1 on click of anchor tags. I am able to achieve this before the application has packaged but after application has packaged, I get error:vbscript process reported unknown error code 1 and registry doesn't set to 1 or 0.

Please note: I am using regedit with regedit.putvalue here to update the values

This question below has info about what I tried.
[link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56750842/setting-and-unsetting-registry-using-regedit-replace-registry-value-from-1-to-0)

What I tried

```
dropDownBtn=`

   <button id="dropDown" class="dropdown" data-toggle="off">Set/Unset Registry</button>
     <div id="dropDowncontent" class="content" data-state="closed">
        <ul>
            <p> <b>Set or Unset Registry</b></p>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="setRegistryValue()">Set</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="unsetRegistryValue()" >Unset</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

**update on this question**
I use npm builder "electron-packager --out winx64 --no-prune --asar" with asar enabled this doesn't work.

The registry doesn't have access from asar package, I guess

Comment: How is this question different from the other question? Please show the code that is throwing the error as well as the full error message.

Comment: I have added dropdown to set(1) and unset (0) on click of each href. I see this error

Comment: Is the question/problem  clear now?

Comment: Not really. You have yet to show any VBScript code.

Comment: Truth is I don't have vbscript code at all!!! This is electron framework using nodejs

Answer (score 0):

First, set the following code in package.json in build

```
"extraResources": [
  {
    "from": "node_modules/regedit/vbs",
    "to": "regedit/vbs",
    "filter": [
      "**/*"
    ]
  }
]
```

Second, set the following code where you use regedit

let regedit = require('regedit');
regedit.setExternalVBSLocation('resources/regedit/vbs');

For more info, refer:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/regedit#a-note-about-electron
2. https://github.com/ironSource/node-regedit/issues/60

Comment: tried out the thing but not working for me